# PHP SOAP request fails

Tags: php, soap

I have to send a request to a remote SOAP endpoint. This is the SOAP request that PHP generates, and it fails:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:GetParameterList>
         <param>TKERES</param>
      </ns1:GetParameterList>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

If I write the request XML manually this way and send it via cURL, it works perfectly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <GetParameterList xmlns="http://tempuri.org">
            <param>TKERES</param>
        </GetParameterList>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Why do the first fail while the second one works correctly?

Answer (score 0):

What is obvious here is that your first snippet (the one that doesn't work) is different from the one that works.

Specifically the property below looks to be in totally different places.

> xmlns="http://tempuri.org"

I know from experience with SOAP that sometimes a change like this can cause it to fail. So, try if you can to adjust the way that PHP generates the request in order to match it with your XML hand written one.